# Plagiarism - inconsistent moderation?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

There were two answers given on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38973495/15498). One of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52726120/15498) included a quote from a third party site (linked) without indicating that it was a quote.

A [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53391853/15498) (deleted by mod action) also included a link to the same page and a *larger* quote (unindicated).

On both answers (before deletion) I had left a comment:

> You ought to put content copied verbatim from the link in a quote block to make clear that you're not attempting to assert authorship of it

When I check back later, the second answer had been deleted as being plagiarism of the first. But the only content they *shared* was the link to the same page and the portion of the page quoted by the first. The second answer didn't copy any content that *correctly* may be attributed to the first answer's author.

So if the second answer was plagiarism, by my reckoning it was plagiarism of the third party site (although a link was provided). So I raised a flag on the first answer stating it should also be closed as plagiarism. However, this flag has since been declined.

If one is plagiarism, both were plagiarism of the third party site. On the other hand, if the first could be fixed (as per my comment, which has been done since by a mod) by simply correcting the quote, so could the second have been and they would not have shared any (meagre) original content.

So my question is, what part of my reasoning has been incorrect?

Comment: Oddly the deleted post seems to have spam flags which got marked valid..

Comment: Plagiarism is pretty thin in my book when the alleged original is on the exact same page.  It just isn't going to fool anybody.   No wonky upvotes either, it is merely an unnecessary answer, that's all.  A DV is usually good enough.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to have two answers with the same quote from the same source.  The second answer would merit deletion for being an exact duplicate of another answer posted months earlier.  That earlier post was poor, but fixable.  It didn't *properly* cite the source, but given that it tried to (even though they failed) there's enough of a demonstration of good faith to simply fix the citation for them (or have them fix it).  There's no need to delete the post.  The second wasn't fixable.  Yes, it had the same improper citation problem, but even if that were to be fixed, it'd still just be an exact duplicate of an earlier answer.  There's just no fixing that.

Comment: But don't plagiarism flags count worse against someone that removing duplicates? Also, as I say, the quoted section was *larger*. They may have felt that the additional parts of the quote were important (but hadn't expended the effort to explain if so)

Comment: E.g. the second answer included in their quote the part "You can use CLI, PowerShell, or Templates" whereas the first answer merely stated "You cannot use Portal". I'm not saying I thought either answer was good/great, just that they deserved to be treated somewhat equally then judged on their merits (if not closed)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever There is not special "plagiarism" flag.  Moderators handling flags for plagiarism may check to see if there's a history of plagiarism in the past, and whether past instances looked like sloppy citations or clear malicious intent to take credit for others' work, and potentially respond to future flags differently as a result.